# DOM - Crear un objeto en un formulario

Tags: javascript, dom

Tengo el siguiente código con **funciones DOM** el cual muestra un texto con un color de fondo.

```
//Crear un div mediante DOM.
function crearCajaResumen(){
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    var texto = document.createTextNode("Texto");
    div.setAttribute("style", "background-color: #FE775A;");
    div.appendChild(texto);
    document.body.appendChild(div);
}
```

¿Cómo se le puede añadir un tamaño (ancho y alto) a este div? ¿Existen atributos en el style como width o height para poder añadirlo a "setAtrribute"?

Debería constar los siguientes elementos:

- -Un título centrado en la caja del div.
- -3 líneas de texto cualquiera.
- -Un tamaño del div de 280x170.
- -El div/caja debe estar alineado dentro del  arriba a la izquierda.

http://subefotos.com/ver/?2f8bfe4b68e9cbdc75c720dfbaafb1c2o.png

¿A qué se debe el fallo de dimensiones y localización?

Comment: Si, existe `width` y `height` como atributos para modificar en CSS, te recomiendo tengas a la mano referencias de CSS para saber qué puedes y qué no se puede modificar: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/

Answer (score 0):

Simple, el objeto `div` tiene una propiedad llamada `style`, mediante la cual puedes acceder a los atributos `css` que desees, entonces, tu código cambiaria así:

```js
//Crear un div mediante DOM.
function crearCajaResumen() {
  var div = document.createElement("div");
  var texto = document.createTextNode("Texto");

  div.style.backgroundColor = "#FE775A";
  div.style.width = "100px";
  div.style.heigth = "100px";
  
  div.appendChild(texto);
  document.body.appendChild(div);
}

crearCajaResumen();
```

Comment: No sé porqué el div no coge las dimensiones de altura que le otorto, ¿igual porque supera el 100% del documento? Te pongo la imagen que quiero que salga: http://subefotos.com/ver/?2f8bfe4b68e9cbdc75c720dfbaafb1c2o.png